# Slices in volumetric space in R

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, r-plotly

Im trying to make a plot_ly surface plot with two surfaces that cross-section, ie mapping one surface on the Z plane, and another surface mapped on the X plane.

The surface on the z-plane is working fine, but adding a second surface in another plane is tripping me up. I'm probably misunderstanding something about how plot_ly handles data.

I'm trying to do something like this, but I can't get the code from this plot working in my own R (RStudio)
https://plot.ly/~schippkus/0/slices-in-volumetric-data/#plot

Here a reproducible example with one-surface working, and the two-surface being odd. The data created in this sample has the same dimensions as the data I am working on. It originally comes in a 3-dimensional array, that I force into this format.

```
library(plotly); library(tidyverse); 

    x = 1:91
    y = 1:109
    z = 1:91

    val = as.numeric(scale(sample(length(x)*length(y)*length(z))))

    DATA = expand.grid(X=x,Y=y,Z=z) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
      mutate(Val = val)

    getTrace = function(data,plane,slice){
      require(tidyverse)
      tmp = data %>% filter(get(plane) %in% slice)

      Trace = list(
        x = tmp %>% select(X) %>% unique() %>% unlist() %>% unname(),
        y = tmp %>% select(Y) %>% unique() %>% unlist() %>% unname(),
        z = tmp %>% select(Z) %>% unique() %>% unlist() %>% unname()
      )

      switch(plane,
             "Z"={
               oneplane = expand.grid(x = Trace$x, y = Trace$y)
               oneplane$z <- tmp %>% select(Val) %>% unlist() %>% unname()

               Trace$SurfaceColor = as.matrix(spread(oneplane, key = x, value = z)[, -1]) %>% unname()
               Trace$z <- matrix(slice, ncol=ncol(Trace$SurfaceColor), nrow=nrow(Trace$SurfaceColor))
               Trace
             },
             "Y"={
               oneplane = expand.grid(x = Trace$x, z = Trace$z)
               oneplane$y <- tmp %>% select(Val) %>% unlist() %>% unname()

               Trace$SurfaceColor = as.matrix(spread(oneplane, key = z, value = y)[, -1]) %>% unname()
               Trace$y <- matrix(slice, ncol=ncol(Trace$SurfaceColor), nrow=nrow(Trace$SurfaceColor))
               Trace
             },
             "X"={
               oneplane = expand.grid(y = Trace$y, z = Trace$z)
               oneplane$x <- tmp %>% select(Val) %>% unlist() %>% unname()

               Trace$SurfaceColor = as.matrix(spread(oneplane, key = y, value = x)[, -1]) %>% unname()
               Trace$x <- matrix(slice, ncol=ncol(Trace$SurfaceColor), nrow=nrow(Trace$SurfaceColor))
               Trace
             }
      )
    }

    Trace1 = getTrace(DATA,"Z",45)
    Trace2 = getTrace(DATA,"Y",45)

    # This works as intended (except I can't seem to make the surface greyscale)
    plot_ly() %>% 
      add_trace(x=Trace1$x,
                y=Trace1$y,
                z=Trace1$z, 
                type="surface", 
                cauto=T,
                surfacecolor=Trace1$SurfaceColor,
                colorscale=c("white","black")
      )  %>%
      layout(title="Ok one-surface plot",
             scene = list(
        aspectratio = list(
          x = 91/109, 
          y = 1, 
          z = 91/109
        ), 
        xaxis = list(
          backgroundcolor = "rgb(230, 230,230)", 
          gridcolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)", 
          showbackground = TRUE, 
          zerolinecolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
          range=c(1,91)
        ), 
        yaxis = list(
          backgroundcolor = "rgb(230, 230,230)", 
          gridcolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)", 
          showbackground = TRUE, 
          zerolinecolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
          range=c(1,109)
        ), 
        zaxis = list(
          backgroundcolor = "rgb(230, 230,230)", 
          gridcolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)", 
          range = c(1, 91), 
          showbackground = TRUE, 
          zerolinecolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        )
      ))

    # This definately does not do as intended
    plot_ly() %>% 
      add_trace(x=Trace1$x,
                y=Trace1$y,
                z=Trace1$z, 
                type="surface", 
                cauto=T,
                surfacecolor=Trace1$SurfaceColor,
                colorscale=c("white","black")
      ) %>%
      add_trace(x=Trace2$x,
                y=Trace2$y,
                z=Trace2$z, 
                type="surface", 
                cauto=T,
                surfacecolor=Trace2$SurfaceColor,
                colorscale=c("white","black")
      ) %>%
      layout(title="Bogus plot",
             scene = list(
               aspectratio = list(
                 x = 91/109, 
                 y = 1, 
                 z = 91/109
               ), 
               xaxis = list(
                 backgroundcolor = "rgb(230, 230,230)", 
                 gridcolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)", 
                 showbackground = TRUE, 
                 zerolinecolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                 range=c(1,91)
               ), 
               yaxis = list(
                 backgroundcolor = "rgb(230, 230,230)", 
                 gridcolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)", 
                 showbackground = TRUE, 
                 zerolinecolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                 range=c(1,109)
               ), 
               zaxis = list(
                 backgroundcolor = "rgb(230, 230,230)", 
                 gridcolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)", 
                 range = c(1, 91), 
                 showbackground = TRUE, 
                 zerolinecolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
               )
             ))
```

Comment: Might want to check the plotly version you are using. You are probably on the development version. Try the CRAN one (4.7.1).

Comment: Just double checked my version, and it is 4.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Trace2, `z` is an integer. And I believe, `z` in both traces needs to be a matrix in order to work.

```
> class(Trace2$y)
[1] "matrix"
> class(Trace2$z)
[1] "integer"
```

So using a simpler example with both `z` a matrix, it works. In the first matrix, all z values are the same (matrix2 = 6). But in the second, the `y` values are constant, but the `z` values are different.

```
matrix2 <- c(
  c(6,6,6,6,6,6),
  c(6,6,6,6,6,6),
  c(6,6,6,6,6,6),
  c(6,6,6,6,6,6)
)
dim(matrix2) <- c(6,4)

x <- c(1,2,3,4,5, 6)
y <- c(1,2,3,4)
rownames(matrix2) <- x
colnames(matrix2) <- y


plot_ly() %>% add_surface(z~matrix2, x= x, y = y)

matrix22 <- c(
  c(5,5.5,6,6.5),
  c(5,5.5,6,6.5),
  c(5,5.5,6,6.5),
  c(5,5.5,6,6.5)
)
dim(matrix22) <- c(4,4)

x2 <- c(1,2,3,4)
y2 <- c(3,3,3,3)
rownames(matrix22) <- x2
colnames(matrix22) <- y2

plot_ly() %>% add_surface(z~matrix22, x= x2, y = y2) %>% add_surface(z~matrix2, x= x, y = y)
```

Gives this:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! This example is helping me understand surface plots better! It was just what I needed to tinker around with to get how they all relate to eachother.