# Problem to draw an inclined plane using plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, surface, plane

I am a recent R user and I have a similar problem to the mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450420/slices-in-volumetric-space-in-r), but I couldn’t find a solution. I would like to draw a vertical plane using plotly. This plane is intended to cross another surface, previously drawn, so (I think) it has to designed as a surface.  But this plane must not be parallel to one of the x and y axes, but rather cross these axes, for example, at points x = 25 and y = 20. I tried to change the routine presented by [MLavoie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3396821/mlavoie) (as follows), but the result it was an inclined plane. I also looked in other answers and couldn't find a solution. My code follows and also the plane follows below:

```
matrix22 <- c(
  c(5, 5.8, 6.2, 7.0),
  c(5, 5.8, 6.2, 7.0),
  c(5, 5.8, 6.2, 7.0),
  c(5, 5.8, 6.2, 7.0)
)
dim(matrix22) <- c(4,4)

x2 <- c(0,10,15,25)
y2 <- c(20,12,8,0)

rownames(matrix22) <- x2
colnames(matrix22) <- y2
g2 <- plot_ly() %>% add_surface(z~matrix22, x= x2, y = y2)
g2
```

Comment: To have a plane parallel to an axis, you need values that reflect that parallelism. In other words, one variable would need to have all of the same values for this to occur.

Comment: @Kat, thanks for your answeer. But, as I mentioned before, I would like to draw a vertical plan that is not parallel to one of the axes. I tried many combinations of values in matrix22, x2 and y2, but I couldn't find the draw the plane the way I wanted.

Comment: I did misread your information. However, now I need to ask, why do you consider the plane to be inclined? When would it not be *inclined*?

Comment: @Kat, thanks for your reply. I'm not sure I can express my ideas correctly (English is not my first language) I would like to draw a plane that crosses the x and y axes and is parallel to the z axis. Trying to make it clearer, imagine a plane whose coordinates (x,y,z) are (25,0,0), (0, 20,0) (25,10,0) and (0,20,10)

Comment: To have a plane parallel to the z-axis, either x or y will have uniform values. In the example question, you have linked in your post, the plane parallel to the z-axis has all the same values for the y-axis.